# Sorting & Filtering in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

I'm having some issues with the Sorting & Filtering Options in excel.

My datas Are: D1, D2, D3, ... , D78, D79, D80,... Etc.

Letters may vary, and a number can repeat itself while having a different letter.

Per example:

> D40
>   D41
>   I41
>   D42
>   V43
>   D44
>   D45
>   D46
>   V46
>   ...

When Sorting from A to Z, it does:

```
D1
D10
D11
D12
D13
D14
...
D29
D3
D30
D31
...
```

**My question is**
What is causing this ? & and how can I stop Excel to do this and do this instead:

```
D1
D2
D3
...
D10
D11
D12
...
```

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=--MID(A1,2,9999)
```

and copy down.  Then sort cols **A** and **B** by **B**.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not do anything. It looks like `=MID` is not a valid function...


EDIT: I forgot to say that I am using a French Version of Excel. Found out that the translation of `=MID` is `=STXT`.

Although, this command did the same Sorting as the usual.